# How to get tools/source.properties on Android SDK (in Travis)?

Tags: java, android, maven, travis-ci, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to build `javaocr` on Travis and [the `com.simpligility.maven.plugins:android-maven-plugin:4.1.1` Maven plugin wants to read `tools/source.properties` in the Android SDK root](https://travis-ci.org/krichter722/javaocr/builds/178875130). How can I provide this file? I cannot install the complete SDK since it will exceed the space limitation of the Travis CI service, but I'm sure there's a specific component which needs to be installed.

I have no idea about the Android API version or whatever is needed, but I'll figure it out if necessary. My current motivation is to verify the complete project on Travis after I made changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a travis-ci issue, I reproduced and solved it locally.

> Error reading
>   /home/travis/build/krichter722/javaocr/demos/sampler/android-studio/tools/source.properties

The path is not correct, use `TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR`[env variable](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/) or absolute paths.

As suggested [here](https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin/issues/494), move your resources and manifests to the new location.

> android-maven-plugin-4.0 uses the new Android Studio folder layout
>   which is much more Mavenish. Ie Android resources should be is
>   src\main\res, Android assets in src\main\assets, AndroidManifest.xml
>   in src\main

Install only the necessary components by name or number but never the full SDK.

```
./android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk -a -u -t tools,platform-tools,build-tools-23.0.3,android-23
```

I did a phew changes to your pom.xml files based on [this response](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/issues/457) and [this manual](https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven-android/)

> You need to replace the plugin with groupId
>   "com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2" with
>   "com.simpligility.maven.plugins" due to a compatibility issue.
>
> So the new plugin is: 
>   com.simpligility.maven.plugins
>   android-maven-plugin 4.1.1
>     21 
>   true
>   true 
>   true

Comment: Looks very convincing. Could you quickly provide this as [PR on github.com](https://github.com/krichter722/javaocr/pulls)?

Comment: This works indeed locally, but not on travis-ci.org. Providing information in images is a bit sadist... Make a PR to get the points.

Comment: @KarlRichter: "sadist"?

Comment: Please don't use images where you can use text. *Copy and paste* the text into your post please so it can be found when searching.

Comment: I deleted the images, the relevant bits were already included as text. It's not the spirit of SO to create PR and a full update of a legacy project solving all the possible issues.